# C++: How to allocate and fill dynamic array of a struct passed by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a very simple structure for adding `size` field to dynamic arrays:

```
template <typename T>
struct sized_array {
    int size;
    T* array;
};
```

I cannot use `std::vector` or `std::array`. The function to fill the array initializes the `sized_array.array` field and fills it with random integers:

```
void array_fill(sized_array<int> &array, int size = ARRAY_SIZE) {
    array.array = new int[size];
    array.size  = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array.array[i] = random_in_range(RANDOM_MIN, RANDOM_MAX);
    }
}
```

The other functions, `array_join` and `array_print` print the contents of an array:

```
string array_join(sized_array<int> &array, string delimiter) {
    string text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
        text += array.array[i];
        if (i < array.size) text += delimiter;
    }

    return text;
}

void array_print(sized_array<int> &array) {
    cout << "array(" << array.size << ") = [";
    cout << array_join(array, ", ") << "]" << endl;
}
```

The array variable is declared like so, and the program runs this code:

```
sized_array<int> number_array;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    array_fill(number_array);
    array_print(number_array);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging, the array shows this value when first initialized, then appears to take the first returned value of `random_in_range` and never change, staying at one element -- the first returned value.

[image]

When printed, the array appears to be filled with random ASCII characters, and the first element is never the one it was (even though the debugger displayed it had one element).

What is the cause of this and how to avoid this problem?

Comment: 1) All debugger sees is a `T*`, and doesn't know whether it's a pointer to a single `T`, or an array of those, so it shows you the value of `*array`. 2) "_When printed, the array appears to be filled with random ASCII characters_" No, it doesn't appear that way. If you actually printed, the array, you would see that. The code that joins the array into a string, does it. `text += array.array[i]` does not, actually, convert the number to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When printed, the array appears to be filled with random ASCII characters

This is because you have an error in your `array_join` function:

```
text += array.array[i];
```

This would append an `int` re-interpreted as `char`, *not* a decimal representation of the number.

Use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to fix the problem:

```
text += std::to_string(array.array[i]);
```

If you are restricted to a C++ version prior to C++11, use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any idea why the array elements are invisible in the debugger, and only first one is shown?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer Debugger has no idea it's an array, it treats a pointer-typed variable as a pointer to a single item.